# Javascript inheritance dependency

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, conditional-statements

I wonder if there is any posibility to make inheritance dependent on some condition?
For example I have object named `X` and another two: `Y` and `Z`. I would like to inherit properties from object `Y` or `Z` to object `X`, depending on conditional result I generate.

Example code:

```
function Y(prop1, prop2, prop3) {
  this.prop1 = prop1 || null;
  this.prop2 = prop2 || null;
  this.prop3 = prop3 || null;
}

function Z(prop4, prop5, prop6) {
  this.prop4 = prop4 || null;
  this.prop5 = prop5 || null;
  this.prop6 = prop6 || null;
}

function X() {
  __properties inherited from Y or Z__
}
```

Comment: And how exactly do you create these objects, and how does one inherit from the other. Some code would help.

Comment: `if (condition) x = Object.create(Y) else x = Object.create(Z)`

Comment: @adeneo
`function Y(prop1, prop2, prop3) {
this.prop1 = prop1 || null;
this.prop2 = prop2 || null;
this.prop3 = prop3 || null;
}

function Z(prop4, prop5, prop6) {
this.prop4 = prop4 || null;
this.prop5 = prop5 || null;
this.prop6 = prop6 || null;
}

function X() {
__properties inherited from Y or Z__
}`

Comment: `if (condition) return new Y() else return new Z()`

Comment: Without telling us what you need these `X` objects for, what exactly you mean by "inherit", and what else these objects are supposed to do, your question is not really answerable.

Comment: I wouldn't use this way to define the Objects.
You can do what you've described while using `Object.create()`;
For instance - `var x = {someProp: propValue}` and then `var y = Object.create(x);`

Comment: @Bergi Sorry if my question is imprecise. Maybe I would describe what I really want to achieve. I have two object constructors defined by:    function FieldSkills(...params) { *defined params* }  function GoalkeeperSkills(...params) { *defined params* }    then I want to generate random value which would determine what constructor I will choose for creating object (that's not a problem in this case). I just wondered if there is any possibility to fill another object constructor, i.e.    function Skills() { empty }    dinamically with properties from determined earlier object constructor.

Comment: @Roysh Okay, I see point of your explanation. Thanks!